# how can I get the space " " as a char?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a `text`: `"The camel is big"`, then I look for letter `"e"` and then I want to store the next two letters in string variables, so my `next1` will get value `"l"` and `next2` will store space `" "`; but compiler throws an exception with message that *Index was outside the bounds of the array*. here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    if (text[i]=='e' || text[i]=='E')
    {
        next1 = text[i + 1].ToString();
        next2 = text[i + 2].ToString(); //this throws exception...
    }
}
```

I understandm thanks for your comments, yes it happens when `i` is at the last point, and it tryes to get the next letters that doesn't exsist. well, how can I prevent it, my text is big, and sometime "e" can happen to be the last letter...

Comment: The question title is misleading.  The answer to the title is `' '`. Moreover, the exception does not occur in the example `text` provided.

Answer (score 3):

The second line (`text[i + 2]`) will throw an error when you have an `e` or `E` on the index before the last character in the string. The first line (`text[i + 1]`) will throw if it is the *last* character.

The example string you gave will not throw an exception.

At that point, `text[i + 2]` will indeed be out of bounds of the string (character array).

You need to loop to just before that happens:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - 2; i++)
```

Comment: I don't understand, this can't possibly throw an exception on `i` of `big` as it never hits `i+1` or `i+2` since `i` of `big` cannot pass the conditional `== 'e' || == 'E'` so this would only be out of bounds if `e` or `E` were toward the end of the string.

Comment: @user17753 - Um. When you are in `i` of `big`, the index you are on is `string.Length - 1`. In the line for `next1`, you are still OK with that value. The exception is thrown on the next line - for `next2`, when you try to access `[i + 2]` which is over the length of the string - out of bounds, throwing an exception.

Comment: Yea but the `[i + 2]` line is never executed in `i` of `big`, hence it can't throw.  Now it if were say `The camel is beg` it would definitely throw on `e` of `beg`.

Comment: @user17753 The code the OP has, with the example string shown, doesn't throw an exception.  Run it yourself to see.  Clearly the exception is with some other string not shown that has an `e` or `E` in one of the last two characters.

Comment: @Servy I know it doesn't throw, I was commenting on why this answer says it will throw on `i` of `big`.

Comment: @user17753 - fair point. My lack of attention to details. Answer updated.

Comment: Having said all that, I'd probably write the loop condition as `i != text.Length-2` as it's easier to assert the invariant in that case, but that's more of a style thing I'd suppose.

Answer (score 3):

So what do you expect to happen when there is an `'e'` as the last character of the string?

Should it just not set `next1` and `next2` at all?  Should it default them to `null` or an empty string?

There are generally two options.  Change the `for` loop to just go from 0 to `text.Length-2`, so that you never deal with the last two characters (this means that `next1` and `next2` won't be changed from whatever they were before, or inside of your `if` you need to check if `i+1` is greater than the length of the string an do "something else" if it is, and then do the same for `i+2`.  What "something else" is could be any number of options.

Answer (score 0):

When i is last or almost last element you try to access to element out of array!!
Try to decrease interation in your loop by 2 :)